# How to use IMPDP Oracle Database on MacOS

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, impdp

Im trying to import my oracle database by using IMPDP on MacOS, I've dump file, and SQLDeveloper app already.
But it return

> IMPDP: command not found.

It seam cannot use it in Mac?
How can I use it or any way to run my dump file?
Regards.

Comment: You can use [instant client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html) with the tools package; but the dump file has to be on the DB server, so can you get it there?

Comment: How is your database installed on your Mac? via docker or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

You should find
$ORACLE_HOME/oracle/product/{version}/{sid}/bin

where version is the oracle version

For example /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/impdp

Answer (score 0):

You should install oracle SQL Loader tool in order to enable imp or impdp.

To install file.

- Download Tools Package (DMG) from oracle site
- once double-clicked it will be present in Volumes folder under root directory and the directory will have install_ic.sh
- run the install script and then it will be copied under the download folder from there you can run imp or impdp commmad.